# Getting compilation error while running CGAL code in mac

Tags: macos, cgal

I am trying to use CGAL in a project. I have installed CGAL using brew:

```
brew install cgal
```

Then, I tried to run some simple code. I am trying to run the first code of this webpage:

```
https://doc.cgal.org/4.7-beta1/Manual/introduction.html
```

I have tried to compile the code using the following command:

```
g++ -lcgal points_and_segment.cpp -o points_and_segment
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::detail::get_tss_data(void const*)", referenced from:
      boost::thread_specific_ptr<double>::get() const in points_and_segment-78cb9a.o
  "boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)", referenced from:
      boost::thread_specific_ptr<double>::reset(double*) in points_and_segment-78cb9a.o
      boost::thread_specific_ptr<double>::~thread_specific_ptr() in points_and_segment-78cb9a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried to include -lboost or -lboost_thread in the command. But then I am getting the following errors:

```
ld: library not found for -lboost
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ld: library not found for -lboost_thread
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried the same with -v. Then I get the following:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.11.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name points_and_segment.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 274.2 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -resource-dir /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0 -stdlib=libc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/abureyanahmed/cgal_test -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 143 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.11.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/vf/b6nrfcl95l56768gldg25r1m0000gn/T/points_and_segment-c5ee94.o -x c++ points_and_segment.cpp
clang -cc1 version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1) default target x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.11.0 -o points_and_segment -lcgal -lboost /var/folders/vf/b6nrfcl95l56768gldg25r1m0000gn/T/points_and_segment-c5ee94.o -lc++ -lSystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
ld: library not found for -lboost
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have looked for the cgal installation folder. It is the following path in my machine:

```
cd /usr/local/opt/cgal/
```

The folder for boost is:

```
cd /usr/local/opt/boost/
.brew/                INSTALL_RECEIPT.json  include/              lib/
```

Comment: Read the doc for `-L`? Or use `cmake` since that's the build system supported by CGAL.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this too. This website helped:

https://discourse.brew.sh/t/could-not-link-to-boost/2125/4

Comment: Hi sef, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)